# listpicker fullmode not updating selection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I've created  a test app from an app I'm working on.  I have a listpicker with a set of colors for some reason when it goes to fullmode the selection is not being updated.

I've download 2 examples of this and I do not see what I'm missing. thanks

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="lstColorsItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding pickedColorBlock}" Height="30" Width="30"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding pickedColor}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="fulllstColorsItemTemplate" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding pickedColorBlock}" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="0,0,10,10"  />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding pickedColor}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="20" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="13,113,143,0">
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lstColors"  Width="225"                             
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lstColorsItemTemplate}" 
                            FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource fulllstColorsItemTemplate}"
                            Header="Font Color"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                            Background="#FFF4F4F5"
                            CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

the code behind

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) //without ToDoTableEntries  not set as observablcollection throws null error (never counts up)
    {

        List<colorChoices> source = new List<colorChoices>();
        source.Add(new colorChoices() { pickedColorBlock = Colors.Black.ToString(), pickedColor = "Black", pickedSolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) });
        source.Add(new colorChoices() { pickedColorBlock = Colors.White.ToString(), pickedColor = "White", pickedSolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White) });
        source.Add(new colorChoices() { pickedColorBlock = Colors.Red.ToString(), pickedColor = "Red", pickedSolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) });
        source.Add(new colorChoices() { pickedColorBlock = Colors.Brown.ToString(), pickedColor = "Brown", pickedSolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown) });
        source.Add(new colorChoices() { pickedColorBlock = Colors.Blue.ToString(), pickedColor = "Blue", pickedSolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) });
        source.Add(new colorChoices() { pickedColorBlock = Colors.Gray.ToString(), pickedColor = "Gray", pickedSolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray) });

        lstColors.ItemsSource = source;

    }

    class colorChoices
    {

        public string pickedColorBlock { get; set; }
        public string pickedColor {get; set;}
        public SolidColorBrush pickedSolidColorBrush {get; set;}

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not getting updated?  Do you mean you can't tell which item in FullScreenMode is the SelectedItem?

Comment: yes sorry, when I click on my list it take me to the fullmode screen I choose my new color and it returns me to my original page but the SelectedItem does not change it stays the first option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because it reloads the ItemSource in `protected override void OnNavigatedTo`

Set the ItemSource in the Constructor, it will solve your problem.

---

To see what I mean put a break point at `lstColors.ItemsSource = source` it will break the first time the app gets loaded and it will break once it gets back from the Full Page Mode, basically resetting the list.

Comment: Thanks. that worked on my test app (the one I posted) odd thing is it will not work on my "real" app.  I copied the code from my test app and pasted to my real app and it will not work. I uninstall and reinstalled the windows phone toolkit and noticed once I did that when I select the color it goes to the full screen page I choose my color it comes back to the page but the selection is not changed but if I click on the color again before it goes to the full screen it changes the color selection to what I previously picked.???

Comment: right now trying to copy and paste code from real app to test app  and see what breaks it. but noticed test app is windows phone Silverlight 8.1 and real app is windows phone 8.  could that do it?  I did upgrade my real app  to 8.1 but that didn't fix it...

Comment: @user2712080 I tested it on WP8.0 SL, it works for me.  It seems to me your "real" app is different than your "test" app (which works).  My guess is your "real" app is messing with the ListPicker as well.

Comment: ok. you were correct moving it up to the constructor fixed it...not sure why my app is broke but I've had to move everything over to the test app to get it to work. it works now, I may never know what broke it.  thanks